How to run fsck on ext4 partition under MacOS?
I would like to check a  file system on an SD card for corruption. It's formatted as ext4 and I would like to run basically fsck.ext4 like on Linux.
It seems that only the modules for exfat, msdos, hfs and cs are installed.
How can I run it on an ext4 partition?
MacOS Sonoma, Intel

There is no built-in support for ext4 in macOS. You would either have to install third-party software or run Linux in a VM.
